# Will Ubuntu Phone and Tablet have Bash?

Tags: command-line, apt, ubuntu-touch

Will the Ubuntu for phone and tablet have the staple software suite installed, such as the Terminal etc? Will updates be possible using apt-get? In short will Ubuntu be Ubuntu?

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/a/259620/25656

Answer (score 2):

There is a terminal emulator app being deloped: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps/Terminal

And: at least on the touch developer preview I am running, there is bash installed (that is accessible via ssh) and I can run apt-get

Answer (score 1):

It definitely will be Ubuntu as all Ubuntus will be Ubuntu. But the Terminal itself is not yet part of the preview.

Stay tuned it will come soon.